# Track/Observe TextBox value changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there is any way to detect text box value changed , whether users changes it explicitly or some java script code modified the text box? I need to detect this change.

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481152/jquery-how-to-detect-a-textboxs-content-has-changed

Comment: @GhyathSerhal, I need also to detect the value if value is changed from javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To track for user changes you can add a handler for key presses:

```
$(selector).keypress(function() {
    // your code
});
```

**Update**: besides watching for key presses, 
<strike>you can use the `change` function to watch from changes via JavaScript</strike>. It won't work immediatly for user changes (is only called after the input loses focus), but together with the `keypress` I believe you cover all cases:

```
$(selector).change(function() {
    // the same code
});

setTimeout(function() { $(selector).val("changed"); }, 2000); // Will trigger the change
```

Edit: sorry, it seemed to work for JavaScript too, but I was mistaken... [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546348/520779), however, will be able to solve your problem (tested with `setTimeout`, and it was able to detect the change).

I posted an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/RZP7G/) in jsFiddle. With this new `watch` plugin, you no longer need `keypress` or `change`: it will work for key typing, copy/pasting, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: @user960567 Have you tried the linked question suggestion? Check my updated answer, I posted an example at jsFiddle.

Comment: This is not a good to have timer to check the value changed every time.

Comment: @user960567 I agree. However, AFAIK polling is the only solution that will work for JavaScript also (a combination of `keypress` and `change` works for all user scenarios - typing, cut/paste, drag and drop - but not for JavaScript). This, or modifying your scripts so none of them changes the input field without also calling your code...

Comment: I am marking your post as answer but it is worth to only fallback to alternative/polyfill if browser does not support the native one. For example, FF natively support watch. Other browser support DOMAttrModified. Check this for improve your version, http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/. BTW, Thanks.