# How do I validate a decimal field with jquery and regex?

Tags: jquery

this is what I have so far:

```
$j(element)..keypress(function(e){
        var val = $j(this).val();
        if (("1234567890.").indexOf(e.charCode) > -1){
            if (val.length > 0){
                var regex = /(\+|-)?(\d*\.\d*)/;
                if (regex.test(val)){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }       
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

but for some reason, the text field only allows one character... and not even a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of @elclanrs and @mgibsonbr, I came to this:

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
    $j("input").keypress(function(e) {
        var val = $j(this).val();
        var regex = /^(\+|-)?(\d*\.?\d*)$/;
        if (regex.test(val + String.fromCharCode(e.charCode))) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

which can be tested here: http://jsfiddle.net/9U2Mw/5/

Comment: Type `+`, click before it, type `2`. IMHO you're making users' lifes more difficult, without preventing invalid input for all cases. But I already presented my opinion, if you really prefer the `keypress` approach, go with it.

Comment: oh, well for that, I'd just need to find a way to not allow typing before a + or -

Answer (score 2):

This checks a decimal number, with an optional +/- sign character. Found under 5sec in google.
`/^\s*(\+|-)?((\d+(\.\d+)?)|(\.\d+))\s*$/`

Comment: what's wrong with doing it this way? (\+|-)?(\d*\.\d*)  this makes it so the decimal is optional, but the decimal itsself can still be present.

Comment: I didn't check the actual code but it seems correct, I just copy/pasted from http://ntt.cc/2008/05/10/over-10-useful-javascript-regular-expression-functions-to-improve-your-web-applications-efficiency.html

Comment: apparently, the problem is that I'm not doing the test after the text has been entered or something

Comment: Why do you need to do it in the `keypress` event? I've been trying solutions but it gets complicated. Basically, the first character and the `.` get rejected. I tried with `keyup` and it seems to solve the first character thing but not the `.`. It might be easier to just validate with a button...Look http://jsfiddle.net/9U2Mw/2/

Comment: but it needs to be as they type.. otherwise whats the point of a forced validation field? =p

Comment: What about just detecting numbers and `.` on `keypress` with something like `if ( (e.which >= 48 && e.which <= 57) || e.which == 190 || e.which == 110 ) { // blabla }`. And then validate on submit? There's still a small chance they might input something invalid like `12.4.55` tho.

Answer (score 2):

First, shouldn't the return be the opposite? `true` if the test succeeds, `false` otherwise?

Second, `.` in a regex means "any character". If you want to match just a dot, use `\.`

This way your regex will work. However, for a better result, use the regex provided by elclanrs.

Note: it seems the value still hasn't changed when the `keypress` runs, so it's the old value that is being matched, not the new one.

**Update**: this is **not** an ideal solution, but will work nonetheless - You can use the code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546348/520779) to watch for changes in the input's value (it uses polling, though):

```
$(element).watch("value", function(propName, oldVal, newVal) {
    var regex = /^(\d*\.?\d*)$/;
    if (!regex.test(newVal)){
        $(this).val(oldVal);
    }
});
```

Comment: yeah, I noticed that after, I posted. but on Rubular.com, this (\+|-)?(\d*\.\d*)  works with this test string: 23.43 23. .32 0.23 43.54 23 -23 -45.34 -.43 -0.34   but now I can't type anything in the text field

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that (see my update). We need to find a way to do the check for the updated string...

Comment: hmm. I must check the jquery api then

Comment: if you find a better solution, post here, I'm interested in it too. However, see my update for a short-term workaround.

Comment: i'll update with my current function. it behaves the same as in my original question, but I feel better about it.

Comment: If you don't want to try my solution, here are some ways of improving yours: You're forgetting the `^` and `$` in the beginning/end of your regex (it must match **all** the input, not any part of it). Also, make the `\.?` optional, or everything will break unless the first char you type is `'.'`. At last, include `+` and `-` as valid characters in your `indexOf` test (it'd also be good to include `\b` and to allow arrow keys, or the field will be hard to navigate/edit). Hope it helps!

Comment: awesome, thanks. this is the fiddle I've come up with: http://jsfiddle.net/9U2Mw/4/  now it just needs to not allow 2 '.'

Comment: Try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/NJNkc/), made it using the contributions I got after asking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9205164/520779). If you don't like the `goodPrefix` thing, just adapt it to always reject invalid inputs (but according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205475/520779), it's not necessarily a good idea...).

Comment: this is what I think might be the best solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205380/356849