# Disallow decimal into textbox not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have a `textbox` where user can insert only `numbers`. So I tried with below link

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yrshaikh/44pc78pj/)

But still I am able to insert [**.**]  (decimal) in the textbox. Below is what I tried

```
 $(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {    
       $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
        if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
```

Textbox

```
<igtxt:WebNumericEdit ID="txtNoofPages" Width="24%" runat="server" CssClass="allownumericwithoutdecimal">
            </igtxt:WebNumericEdit>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204783/how-do-i-validate-a-decimal-field-with-jquery-and-regex

Comment: Messing with key input is not user friendly, far better to just show an on–screen hint if the value seems invalid and let the user fix it themselves. Sniffing keys doesn't stop invalid values being pasted, or dragged and dropped into the field, Oh, and `$(this).val()` is just a very inefficient way of doing `this.value`.

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl: the link which u gave accepts `.` decimal. I dont want that..

Comment: it's working fine. I can't insert dot.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I checked this link http://jsfiddle.net/9U2Mw/5/ which is accepting `.` from the post

Comment: try `var regex = /^[+-]?\d+$/;`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: working when i try to enter `.` but it is not working when I copy paste `.` What to do in that condition if user try to copy paste ?

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/9U2Mw/714/

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Working when I try to insert `.` but I am still able to copy paste `.`

Comment: how you copy paste? through mouse? then you need to look at mouse listeners

Comment: @AvinashRaj: no not through mouse, through keyboard, When I copy from notepad and I paste into the textbox. It still accepts `.`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: any help on this ? why it is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you JS Fiddle that is working fine with Firefox, IE and chrome browsers. then i tried this with JQuery with same regex that is working fine.

```js
$("#onlyNumber").on('keypress keyup blur', function(){
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
        if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Number Only</label>
<input type='textbox' id='onlyNumber'>
```

Comment: This cannot be the answer, instead a comment confirming OP's code is working fine.

Comment: See [WorksForMe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: This answer is incorrect because you can still copy from another place and paste into the input field a dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Sorry, didn't got you.  Am I missing something. ?