# Validate html text input as it's typed

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

What's the best way of validating an HTML text input as it's typed? All ways I know of doing it has some drawbacks:

1. Using `$.keypress` you only have access to the input's old value, not the new one. Also, some events (like cutting/pasting using the mouse) won't be detected.
2. Using `$.change` only works when the input loses focus.
3. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1546348/520779) proposes a solution, where you use polling to watch for property changes. In principle, it's possible to validate the new value in the callback, then revert to the old one if invalid. However, besides requiring polling, I'm not sure it's free from race conditions.
4. [This article](https://www.darcyclarke.me/articles/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/) suggests using browser specific features when present, falling back to polling if none is available. Looks like the best approach so far.
5. **[Update]** as pointed in the answers, `$.keyup` give access to the value after update. However, not only it doesn't work for mouse cut/paste, but also fails if you press and hold a key, only releasing after a lot has been entered. Or, if combining `keydown` and `keyup` to save/restore the old value, it breaks if the user types too fast.

None of the solutions above are error free or really safe cross-browsers. Are there better solutions out there, either ready-to-use or in-the-making? Seems to be a common problem, I've attempted to answer [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9108878/520779) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9204783/520779) recently, with no success, and I'm interested in an answer as well.

(A good argument **against** this practice is also welcome, in case there are new problems that would rise if this validation were implemented; however, that seems a common thing in other languages, so I doubt it is a bad thing to want)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `input` (FF) and `propertychange` (all others) events to catch all forms of input including keyboard and rmb cut paste.

http://jsfiddle.net/dFBzW/

```
$('input').bind('input propertychange', function() {
    $('#output').html($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer I found so far, and I wrote [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/NJNkc/) based on it. Worked great on FF, Chrome and Safari, kinda worked on IE6 (got a non-fatal stack overflow sometimes, but who cares about IE6), but failed on Opera (and Konqueror, but I don't care much about it either). So I'm leaving the question open for some more time...

Comment: @mgibsonbr - seems to work in Opera 11.61 for me. What exactly does this example do?

Comment: It attempts to only let the user enter valid numbers, but since this is impossible (while the user is still typing, the value *will* be invalid), it also accept valid prefixes (showing a red border if the whole text is not valid). So, if the user attempts to add or delete characters that will make the input invalid, it reverts to the last saved value. Otherwise, it saves the new value. (Not necessarily something I'd do in a real system, though - see nnnnnn's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205475/520779)) The example fails on Opera 10.63, but since it works on newer versions, it's fine!

Comment: second time I read (FF) what is FF stand for?

Answer (score 6):

> A good argument against this practice is also welcome, in case there are new problems that would rise if this validation were implemented; however, that seems a common thing in other languages, so I doubt it is a bad thing to want.

If by "validate" you mean "prevent invalid characters from being entered at all", I think this is a bad practice. It's confusing for users, who may not be paying close attention and who perhaps aren't even looking at the field while they type (e.g., if they're entering account or phone numbers that they're reading from a piece of paper). The value that actually gets saved/used may be slightly different to the value they thought they'd entered.

If by "validate" you mean "test the current value and draw the user's attention to any problems" by e.g., displaying an error next to the field or changing the background colour, then there is no problem using a combination of several events including keyup, change, blur, paste, click:

```
$("field selector").on("keyup change blur paste cut click", function() { ... });
```

This will catch most normal cases as the user types, and for the clipboard or drag'n'drop cases you at least know that at worst the field will still be validated when the user leaves it. (Obviously you don't allow submit until all errors have been corrected.)

If you process keyup *and* keydown that covers cases where the user held a key down, because most browsers will send repeated keydown events for that.

Comment: Those are good points, I'll think twice before doing this from now on.

Answer (score 5):

In the jQuery world, it's common to leverage plug-ins for these validation tasks. Plug-ins can be relatively easy to use, and their popularity usually reflects in less bugs than code written from scratch.

Input validation is usually split into categories, including:

**1)** Correct input format / Input mask. for example, only A-Z, or say, 10 digit numbers.

**2)** Content existence in a domain. For example, airport code or postal codes.

For **(1)** you can use these relatively popular plug-ins:

[Digital Bush's Masked Input Plugin for Jquery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). It has many options for customisation including spaces, eg:

*from Digital Bush website:*

```
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

The [autoNumeric from decorplanit.com](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) . They have a nice support for numeric, as well as currency, rounding, etc.

*adapted from autoNumeric website:*

```
$('#amountPaid').autoNumeric({aSep: '.', aDec: ','}); // eg, 9.000,00
```

For **(2)**, you can use, for example, [jQuery UI's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), combined with server resource data, in a format like JSON. These are likely to require custom code to lock input, but you can still leverage plug-ins for the basic functionality, and focus on the specific business logic you are creating.

Some text above adapted from  two answers in other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9156636/449024) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185724/449024).

Comment: +1 for the useful references. Some of them still perform weirdly when cut-paste is involved, but for the most common cases they're really better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `oninput`?

HTML example:

```
<input name="username" id="user_name" oninput="readvalue();">
```

javascript:

```
function readvalue() {
    var name = $('#user_name').val();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code

```js
function validatephone(xxxxx) 
{
  var maintainplus = '';
  var numval = xxxxx.value
  if ( numval.charAt(0)=='+' )
  {
    var maintainplus = '';
  }
  curphonevar = numval.replace(/[\\A-Za-z!"£$%^&\-\)\(*+_={};:'@#~,.Š\/<>\" "\?|`¬\]\[]/g,'');
  xxxxx.value = maintainplus + curphonevar;
  var maintainplus = '';
  xxxxx.focus;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" align="MIDDLE" size="30" maxlength="20" onkeyup="validatephone(this);" name="contact"/>
```

Comment: The OP's question was about how the validation should be triggered, not how the validation function itself should be implemented. He already mentioned keyup in his question.

Answer (score 3):

Just for another solution to prevent certain characters, without JQuery...

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="checkInput(event)" />

...

function checkInput(e)
{
    //only alpha-numeric characters
    var ok = /[A-Za-z0-9]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.charCode));
    if (!ok)
        e.preventDefault();
}
```

I don't know if this requires new versions of things or only works on some browsers. Please comment.

Comment: wait no, it actually doesn't: firefox also blocks backspace, arrow keys etc. This can be solved with `|| e.charCode === 0`, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

This also may be helpful

```
$(".cssclass").live("input propertychange", function () {
    //Validate goes here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function validatephone(xxxxx) 
{
  var maintainplus = '';
  var numval = xxxxx.value
  if ( numval.charAt(0)=='+' )
  {
    var maintainplus = '';
  }
  curphonevar = numval.replace(/[\\A-Za-z!"£$%^&\-\)\(*+_={};:'@#~,.Š\/<>\" "\?|`¬\]\[]/g,'');
  xxxxx.value = maintainplus + curphonevar;
  var maintainplus = '';
  xxxxx.focus;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" align="MIDDLE" size="30" maxlength="20" onkeyup="validatephone(this);" name="contact"/>
```

Comment: Explain your answer

Answer (score -3):

```
let that=this;

$(this.element).find("input").keypress(function(e) {
               let character = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

               let newValue =  this.value.substring(0,this.selectionStart) + character + this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd, String(this.value).length);


               if (!that.isFormatValid(newValue, that.getdecimalPoints())) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     e.stopPropagation();
                     return false;
              }

              return true;
        });


        $(this.element).find("input").bind({
              paste: function() {
                     let _this = this;

                     setTimeout( function() {
                           let decimals = that.getdecimalPoints();
                           if (!that.isFormatValid($(_this).val(), decimals)) {                        
                                         $(_this).val('');                        
                           }
                     }, 0);                                                                                                  
                  }
           });
```

Comment: Answers with code should include a brief description about how it answers the question.