# Display message when user exceed limit size of a textbox in asp.net mvc app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an asp.net mvc app where an user can fill a textbox. The textbox field is required and the validation is performed when he clicks on submit.

But I have another concern, I would like to display a message when the user types more than 10 characters in the textbox. This needs to validate without clicking on any validate button.

This is my current code :

```
<span class="field">@Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.Name,new {maxlength=10})</span>
```

With this, the user cannot exceed the character limit, but there is no message displayed. I would like to display a message automatically when he tries to write the eleventh character.

I have followed the suggestion of adricadar, so my property looks like this now :

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Too many characters.")]        
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

But now, when I am trying to access the page, I am getting this exception :

```
errormessagestring or errormessageresourcename must be set but not both
```

Comment: You should go client side

Comment: use jquery, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205164/validate-html-text-input-as-its-typed

Answer (score 1):

You can add on the `Name` property the `StringLength` attribute. This validate the input while the user is typing. This will include *server and client side validation*.

```
[StringLength(10, ErrorMessage = "Too many characters.")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

**Note:** The attribute isn't adding to the input `maxlength=10` attribute, it's adding a custom attribute `data-val-length-max=10`.

Don't forget to include `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`.

Comment: I already add a StringLength attribute on my property, the problem is that the message is displayed only when the user validates the form, until then, he can write any number of characters he wants in the textbox

Comment: @user2443476 I just tested. It allows to write more than 10 values, but it's validating as I'm typing, I can make a gif if you want. Have you included the `jQuery` validate libraries?

Comment: Ok I can't try now but I will keep you informed. I assume I have to remove the "new {maxlength=10})" parameter in my textbox ?

Comment: @user2443476 You are right, I removed that parameter. Also, I further testing it an sometimes you have to click (or to make other action) outside the input (not submit button), when you come back again, it works.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion, and I have an exception error that I describe in my first post.

Comment: @user2443476 What asp.net mvc version you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79498/discussion-between-user2443476-and-adricadar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringLength` of `DataAnnotation` along with `unobtrusive` jquery which will show your error messages in real time. But you will have to enable `unobtrusive` before you can use it.

```
[Required]
[StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Too many characters",MinimumLength=2)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

In view you can enable `unobtrusive` jquery like this

```
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

You can also enable this for whole application if you set this in `web.config`.

Finally you will have to add `ValidationMessageFor` in view to show errors associated with model.

So you final view code looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true; 
@Html.ValidationSummary()

 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```