# How to apply validation in real time while typing itself [Typescript]

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. The closest question I found was:

1. [Validate html text input as it's typed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9205164/validate-html-text-input-as-its-typed) : But they are using `jquery`

The actual project is way too sophisticated but I tried creating a minimal problem statement out of it. I want to validate a date as it is typed-in in real time. I'm using `moment` for validation. I created a custom `validate()` method which is called on `(keydown)="triggerValidate()"`. Inside `value()` there are several checks:

1. Format should be `MM-DD-YYYY` only.
2. No date should be less than 1st Jan, 2015.
3. No date should be above 31st Dec, 2020.

I've created a [stckblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9rbqy) also. But let me explain my logic.

There's a global varibale `isDateValid: boolean` which is set accordingly inside `validate()` method. If it is `false` then `addInvalidStyle()` will be called which will make the border red dynamically. And if it is `true`, then `removeInvalidStyle()` will be called which will remove then apply dynamic css and set the input field back to normal. Here's my code:

**timeselector.component.html**

```
<input [class.warning-border]="isApplied" [(ngModel)]="range" (keydown)="triggerValidate()"/>
```

**timeselector.component.ts**

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core';
import moment from 'moment';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class TimeselectorComponent {

      isDateValid: boolean=true;

      startingCalendarYear = 2015;
      endingCalendarYear = 2020;

      isApplied: boolean = false;

      range;

      triggerValidate() {
        this.validate(this.range);
      }

      validate(range: string) {
        this.isDateValid=true;
        const myDate = moment(range, 'MM-DD-YYYY', true);
        const lastDayOfCalendarYear = moment([this.endingCalendarYear]).endOf('year');
        const firstDayOfCalendarYear = moment([this.startingCalendarYear]).startOf('year');

        if (!myDate.isValid()) {
            this.isDateValid=false;
            this.addInvalidStyles();
        }
        if (myDate.isAfter(lastDayOfCalendarYear)) {
            this.isDateValid=false;
            this.addInvalidStyles();
        }
        if (myDate.isBefore(firstDayOfCalendarYear)) {
            this.isDateValid=false;
            this.addInvalidStyles();
        }
        if (this.isDateValid) {
            this.removeInvalidStyles();
        }
    }
    addInvalidStyles() {
        this.isApplied = true;
    }
    removeInvalidStyles() {
        this.isApplied = false;
    }
}
```

**timeselector.component.css**

```
.warning-border {
    border: 2.8px solid red;
    padding-top: 0.8px !important;
    padding-bottom: 3px !important;
}
```

Or you can directly see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f9rbqy). My problem is that I have to press some key to validate my dates as I'm using `keydown`. I have to press enter to trigger even when the entered date is correct otherwise it will continue showing red alert. Please help me. Is this achievable or not without using `form` of any type.

Comment: hi all, is anything wrong with this question. Is this even doable or am i wasting everyone's time.

Comment: hi all, I tried this also: https://www.sitepoint.com/instant-validation/

Comment: I would suggest using `ReactiveForms` in Angular. Then you can use existing `Validators` or write your own and apply them to each "control" in your form, which will be validated as you type.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, Oh no. I'm sp sorry i cannot do that. this stackblitz is just an excerpt from the actual project. I cant make those changes. :-(

Comment: @Chrillewoodz. Is it not possible with the existing code without touching html ?

Comment: Why can't you make changes? It doesn't require that much in terms of changing the HTML.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz. Sir I undertsnad, but that's not my code. This will have to go through code review by team lean and so much of drama they do. :-(

Comment: @Chrillewoodz. Ok let's make it rective form for some time. but that form should not get submitted at any cost till i press Apply button manually (i've code for that also).

Comment: @Peilonrayz. Ok I'll take care of my spellings. Sorry for that. And as far as code is concerned, there's nothing copyrighted. Its my own code. Even the variable names have been changes. I understand intellectual property rights. Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: @Tanzeel Thank you, your comments are _super_ easy to read now :) Sorry to have been a bother. Hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I've read the comments, if you don't want to change the html code , to achieve your goal you have to add this:

```
import { Component, DoCheck, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import moment from "moment";

@Component({
  selector: "app-timeselector",
  templateUrl: "./timeselector.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./timeselector.component.css"]
})
export class TimeselectorComponent implements DoCheck {

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.validate(this.range);
  }
```

Now you can delete (keydown)="triggerValidate()".

Comment: This is working as expected but can you please explain this a little bit because I'll justify this to my tech lead. thanks in advance.

Comment: The DoCheck() checks all changes in the component, so when you type it apllies the validation at the same time.